# asp.net membership - ident_current('aspnet_Users') retrieves NULL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

I have asp.net Membership configured, and when i do a "Select ident_current('aspnet_Users')" it retrieves NULL, and i have information there. If i do the same command to another table  it returns right.

I'm doing that in Microsoft SQL Management Studio with 'SA' default login.

Comment: That doesn't have any columns with the `IDENTITY` property IIRC so that isn't going to work. AFAIK it uses GUIDs as Primary Keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do this on the aspnet_users table as it uses a Guid as its primary key - I guess the other table you tried had a standard int identity which is why it worked.

What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to get the generated Guid back from a query then use OUTPUT (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1510529/1191903)

Comment: i'm trying to combine the aspnet membership with my own user table. After creating the user in membership i'm trying to get the lastid to insert as FK in my User table

Comment: Are you are doing Membership.CreateUser() to create the user? or are you doing it manually?

Comment: Yes i'm using Membership.CreateUser()

Comment: OK, well it returns a MembershipUser - you can then retrieve the ID via the ProviderUserKey property - give that a try and see if it works.