# How to store the value of last inserted id(PK) into a variable where the primary key is a GUID in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, primary-key, guid

My question is related to the question asked in here  [How to get last inserted id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

But the scope_identity() will not work for me as in my case the primary key value for the table is a GUID value.

Also I have seen the question in here 
[SQL Server - Return value after INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert)

but the link does not explain how can i store the value in a variable. I need to store the value in a variable which I can use for multiple entry.

I am inserting hard coded value into multiple SQL Server tables. All the primary key columns are GUID.

The table structure are as follows.

[image]

This is the code I use to insert data into survey table.

```
 Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim survey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

    Dim SurveyTitle As String = "Diversity Monitoring Survey"
    Dim SurveyDetail As String = ""

    Core.DB.DoQuery("insert into survey(id,title, detail,employerid,userid) values(@id,@title, @detail, @eid, @uid);", Core.DB.SIP("title", SurveyTitle), Core.DB.SIP("detail", SurveyDetail), Core.DB.SIP("eid", LocalHelper.UserEmployerID()), Core.DB.SIP("uid", LocalHelper.UserID()), Core.DB.SIP("id", survey))

 End Sub
```

Where DoQuery is

```
Shared Sub DoQuery(ByVal commandText As String, ByVal ParamArray params As SqlParameter())
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = Nothing

    Try
        conn = GetOpenSqlConnection()
        DoQuery(conn, commandText, params)
    Finally
        If conn IsNot Nothing Then conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Now I want to retrieve of just inserted `SurveyId` value and store it into a variable `strSurveyId`

```
    Dim strSurveyID As String
```

So that I can insert that value in the table `SurveyQuestionCategory`:

```
    Core.DB.DoQuery("insert into surveyquestioncategory(title, detail, surveyid) values(@title, @detail, @sid)", Core.DB.SIP("title", strSurveyQuestionCategoryTitle), Core.DB.SIP("detail", strSurveyQuestionCategoryDetail), Core.DB.SIP("sid", strSurveyID))
```

`scope_identity()` will not work in my case as the the is GUID.

I have tried this

```
        SELECT * from [MPBlLiteDev].[dbo].[Survey] where id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

But it gives me a error 
Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with numeric

Please suggest with code.

Comment: `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: The id is GUID. So scope_identity will not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server - SCOPE\_IDENTITY() for GUIDs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509947/sql-server-scope-identity-for-guids)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the below stored procedure

```
Create proc SPInsertSurvey
(
   @Title varchar(MAX),
   @OutSurveyID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER output
)
as
DECLARE @Table TABLE (SurveyID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
begin

   insert into survey(Title) 
   Output inserted.SurveyID into @Table values (@Title)

   set @OutSurveyID =(select SurveyID from @Table)

end
```

You can execute it by using below Syntax

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @OutSurveyID uniqueidentifier

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SPInsertSurvey]
        @Title = N'''S1''',
        @OutSurveyID = @OutSurveyID OUTPUT

SELECT  @OutSurveyID as N'@OutSurveyID'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

SCOPE_IDENTITY() will only return the newly generated Identity value if there is any, for GUID values you would need a `table variable` with `OUTPUT` clause in your insert statement something like this.....

```
DECLARE @NewIDs TABLE (ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

insert into survey(id,title, detail,employerid,userid) 
OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @NewIDs(ID)
values(@id,@title, @detail, @eid, @uid);

SELECT * FROM @NewIDs
```