# Combine these 3 SQL steps into 1 query

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2017 (In Azure) - when I need to create a new client in our clients database, I have to run three separate queries, and in between each query, do a lookup to be able to populate a part of the next query. I'd like to see if there is a way to combine all this into one query, or, parameterized stored procedure:

All of this takes place in the same database called `Clients`:

Step 1 - Create the client record in `dbo.clients`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.clients
(ClientGuid, Name, Permissions)
VALUES 
(NEWID(), 'Contoso', 1)
```

Step 2 - Get the Primary Key which was auto-created in Step 1:

```
SELECT ClientKey from dbo.clients
WHERE Name = 'Contoso'
```

Now write down the primary key (`ClientKey`) from that record, we'll say `12345678`

Step 3 - Create a new billing code in the `dbo.billingcodes` table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.billingcodes
(BillingCodeGuid, ClientKey, Name, ScoreId)
VALUES
(NEWID(), 12345678, 'Contoso Production Billing Code', 1)
```

How can I combine all this into one query or parameterized stored procedure where all I have to enter in are the two `names` from step 1 and 3 (assume the `Permissions` and `ScoreId` integers are always going to be `1`) and also get an output at the end of the process of the created values for `dbo.clients.ClientKey` and `dbo.billingcodes.BillingCodeGuid`?

Comment: Clever.  The issue I'm having is trying to understand how to get values without having to manually look them up and copy/paste them into a new, separate query.  So I AM stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to get identity of inserted row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

Comment: That thread speaks only to Identity values and does not address getting the value created by `NEWID()`.  I found helpful information here which may guide me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509947/scope-identity-for-guids  Once I formulate the stored procedure and it works correctly, I will post it here as the answer.

Comment: But in your example you're obtaining the ClientKey, which you say is 12345678? So thats clearly a int you are trying to obtain? In fact from the thread I posted the `OUTPUT clause` works for both and is probably the most versatile solution. But of course you can always create a new guid before you insert it, for a single record, but thats trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a procedure that consists of both inserts with a line in between to get the ID of the inserted client.  Assign the ID to a variable and pass it in to the second part.

See this post about some different ways about getting the inserted record’s ID [Best way to get identity of inserted row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

Comment: Makes sense, Joe, thanks for this answer and being willing to assist - I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by using `procedure`. You may find this link for creating procedure in SQL Server [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

In case of **Procedure** , need to insert your data into first table. Then using `IDENT_CURRENT` ([Ident_Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) you'll get your last inserted id from table, which will further use to insert it into next table.