# Getting output from an SqlDataSource INSERT command

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an insert command for which I need the identity row from.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsUser" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Link %>"
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM User WHERE (uID = @uID)"
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO User(uID, FirstName, LastName, UserLogin, UserPassword, UserEmail) VALUES (NEWID(), @FirstName, @LastName, @UserLogin, @UserPassword, @UserEmail) SET @NewUserId=SCOPE_IDENTITY();"
<DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="uID" />
</DeleteParameters>
<InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="UserLogin" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="UserPassword" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="UserEmail" />
    <asp:Parameter DbType="Guid" Direction="Output" Name="NewUserId" />
</InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I'm trying to access the `NewUserId` when the `dsUser` value is inserted.

```
Private Sub dsUser_Inserted(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles dsUser.Inserted
    Dim dvarl = e.Command.Parameters("@NewUserId").Value
    Response.Redirect("editUser.aspx?uid=" + e.Command.Parameters("@NewUserId").Value)
End Sub
```

Once the data is inserted I want to redirect to the edit screen of the newly added User.

Debugging this doesn't really give any clues as to why the output param is not being `SET` properly

[image: debugger]

I'm making progress debugging and found a new error message:

[image]

Which results: `Operand type clash: numeric is incompatible with uniqueidentifier`

Comment: I'm surprised that SQL code works at all. I would have thought that you'd need a semicolon after the `INSERT` statement, before the `SET`.

Comment: You would have to DECLARE the variable as OUTPUT in the SQL script. I'm surprised it doesn't error out actually.

Comment: @Crowcoder, that's not the case. Setting the `Direction` of the command parameter is how it's done. ADO.NET takes care of the rest.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I guess that explains why it doesn't error. But I'm still going to have to verify for myself.

Comment: Would there be any problem if I just generated the Guid with the Guid class in VB.net (Vs SQL newid()) and just saved that and used it later after insertion?

Comment: @Kyle yes, that could be a problem because non-sequential guids like that make poor primary keys. There are ways to generate sequential guids but not with System.Guid.

Comment: @Kyle it works when I try it. Are you sure there is no exception being swallowed? If I force an exception it doesn't raise until after the inserted event handler executes.

Comment: @Crowcoder I debugged further and found an exception like you suggested. I updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I think there was an issue getting the identity/output from the Guid as mentioned here: [SCOPE_IDENTITY() for GUIDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509947/scope-identity-for-guids)

The solution I came up with was to set the output parameter with the `NEWID()` and use the parameter in the insert:

```
InsertCommand="SET @NewUserId=NEWID() INSERT INTO User(uID, FirstName, LastName, UserLogin, UserPassword, UserEmail) VALUES (@NewUserId, @FirstName, @LastName, @UserLogin, @UserPassword, @UserEmail)"
```

Everything now works!